# Button sticks to bottom of page jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I did not find anything related to this, only making the button scrolls down to bottom of page on click but I already got this.

My problem is:

I got an 'Explore Button' on top a slide show that when you click on it the page scrolls down, the thing is, in some screens the slideshow is bigger than the size of the window so you can't see the button unless you scroll down (therefore no point in having the button). I fixed it by adding:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

    var slideHeight = $('.item').height();
    var headerHeight = $('header').height();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();

    $('.exploreImage').css('bottom', (Math.max(headerHeight + slideHeight, windowHeight) - windowHeight) + 20 + "px");

    });
```

But now when I scroll down I want the button to scroll down and stay at the bottom of the window (until a certain height which is the end of the slide show).

I've got so far something similar which is:

```
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
    $('.exploreImage').css('bottom', 0 + "px");

    });
```

But this puts the button at the bottom of the slide show when it scrolls and not bottom of the windows as I want to!

Notice: I need to get this done with jQuery.

Thanks for your help guys!

**EDIT: fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1fr27eLu/7/ but the jQuery doesn't seem to work there!**

Comment: Can you post this on a fiddle so we can see this in action? From the description it sounds like this could be achieved using position: fixed;

Comment: I need to fix it using jQuery and position: fixed makes it disappear.

Comment: Post a codepen or fiddle. Looks like you need an if condition and then fix it at a certain point.

Comment: @Gui A link to jsfiddle, will helps us a lot :)

Comment: Just did, but the jQuery doesn't seem to work there!

Answer (score 0):

This is a poor example, but it may give you something to start with. Incorrect positioning of button has something to do with this:

https://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/

> The vertical scroll position is the same as the number of pixels that are hidden from view above the scrollable area. If the scroll bar is at the very top, or if the element is not scrollable, this number will be 0.

Anyway, here is the sample code that might put you onto the right track:

```js
var screenWidth  = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0); //Max of page size vs window size, or zero
var screenHeight = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientHeight, window.innerHeight || 0);
screenHeight = screenHeight - 100; //correct for jsFiddle
var st, btnFixed=false, bd = $('#btnDIV');

$(window).scroll(function(){
  st = $(window).scrollTop();
  $('#rpt').html( st +'/'+ screenHeight); //DEV
  if (st < screenHeight && !btnFixed){
    bd.css({'top':st*1.3});
  }else{
    bd.css({'top': screenHeight+'px'});
    btnFixed = true
  }
  if (st < screenHeight && btnFixed){
    bd.css({'top':st*1.3});
    btnFixed = true
  }
});
```

```css
html,body{
  100%;
}
div{
  position:relative;
}
#wrap{
  height:2000px;
}
#btnDIV{
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background:red;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="btnDIV"><button class="exploreImage">Explore</button></div>
<div id="rpt"></div>
<div id="wrap"></div>
```

```
#rpt{position:fixed;top:0;right:0;height:40px;width:100px;background:wheat;}
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/ce2c6cad/)</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for helping, I tried it but it's not smooth and it does not look good. Would you happen to know any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

When combined with the other answer, you could use a form of throttle along with the `animate()` method.

I haven't got it perfect, but hopefully you'll see the value.

```
$(window).scroll( $.throttle( 250, btnScroll ) );
```

<kbd>[**jsFiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/a9ydm3bz/)</kbd>

---

Resources:

http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-throttle-debounce-plugin/

https://css-tricks.com/the-difference-between-throttling-and-debouncing/

http://www.paulirish.com/2009/throttled-smartresize-jquery-event-handler/ (see bottom comments)